# Homework - Probability of raining

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

When I was doing my homework in probability, I encounter this question.

"The weather is raining 70% of the time. There are two people that provide weather forecast, A and B, which their prediction are wrong 10% and 40% respectively. Their predictions performance is independent. Given A predict it will rain and B predict it will not, find the probability that the weather is raining."

I can divide the situation into 4 case, which are ‘both A and B are right’, ‘A is right and B is wrong’, ‘A is wrong and B is right’ and ‘both A and B are wrong’, and then use P(A is right and B is wrong) as the answer. This computation is rather simple, but I think I should not ignore ‘the weather is raining 70% of the time’ in the calculation.

Can anyone please tell me if I am missing something in the calculation. This question is related to the topic of conditional probability, total probability theorem, Bayes’ Rule and independence. Thank you.

Comment: When the problem states that, say, A is wrong 10% of the time, does it mean that A declares 10% of all sunny days to me rainy, and 10% of all rainy days to be sunny, or merely that 10% of his predictions are wrong (but we don't know how those 10% are distributed into false positives and false negatives)?

Comment: It means 10% of all predicted sunny days are raining and 10% of all predicted rainy days are sunny.

Comment: x @Edison: What would such a forecaster do if he found himself in a place where it actually rains only 5 % of all days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R$ be the event it rains, $A$ and $B$ be the events that $A$ and $B$ predict it rains. We want $P(R|\,A\cap B^c)$, which you can use Baye's rule to find:
$$
P(R|\,A\cap B^c) = \frac{P(A\cap B^c|R)\cdot P(R)}{P(A\cap B^c)}\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=\frac{P(A\cap B^c|R)\cdot P(R)}{P(A\cap B^c|R)\cdot P(R)+P(A\cap B^c|R^c)\cdot P(R^c)}
$$
You can now find each of the terms in the last expression.

Answer (score 0):

Call $W$, $A$ and $B$ the weather and its predictions by $A$ and $B$, each being $r$ (rain) or $s$ (no rain). Then, $$P(W=r,A=r,B=s)=P(W=r)P(A\ \text{true})P(B\ \text{false}),$$ and $$P(W=s,A=r,B=s)=P(W=s)P(A\ \text{false})P(B\ \text{true}),$$ hence $$P(W=r\mid A=r,B=s)=\frac{P(W=r,A=r,B=s)}{P(W=r,A=r,B=s)+P(W=s,A=r,B=s)}$$ is $$\frac{P(W=r)P(A\ \text{true})P(B\ \text{false})}{P(W=r)P(A\ \text{true})P(B\ \text{false})+P(W=s)P(A\ \text{false})P(B\ \text{true})}.$$
Exercise: List the hypotheses missing from the statement of the problem, that are necessary to justify the computations above.